# Is it OK to have database name the same as user name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Many web services require a database and quite often that is MySQL. Typically, the installation instruction of the software tells you to create a database and a user with permission for that database.

Is it OK to name the user and the DB the same?

For example, I am installing [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) right now and I created a MySQL database "openfire" and MySQL user "openfire". Should I expect any problems? What is the convention?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that is absolutely fine and quite a common practice. They are mutually exclusive in use and will not cause any problems.

All you need to ensure is that they comply with username and schema naming conventions:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-names.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to name the user and the DB the same, you should not have problem.

But from a security point of view you should maybe use another username.

Comment: security by obscurity is not a very good idea

Comment: I voted up to cancel the negative vote, because the answer does not imply that I should employ a security by obscurity method.

Comment: Ditto, because whilst I agree with ptman generally, changing the admin/default username from a default or easily-guessed value IS standard security practice.  And because this does still answer the OP's question.